# Android - Runtime created objects with Dagger

Tags: android, dependency-injection, square, dagger

I came across the dagger library from Square and I'm currently making some tests. I'm new to the DI principle so be kind :)

So, I understand Dagger can inject fields and constructors. I'm also aware that in my activities, I have to `.inject(this);` so that injection can be done at runtime.
But what about an object O that needs to be created after the activity initialization ?

If O has injectable fields, I have to `.inject(O);` before using it otherwise I get a `NullPointerException` when accessing its injected variables. But if I write a injectable constructor, no problem, no runtime exception.
Of course I wrote my @Module according to the documentation.

Isn't it the purpose of Dagger to injects fields with no other code to write ? Do I have to manually `.inject();` all my objects ? There is for sure a thing I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote Dagger supports two kind of injection:

- field injection
- constructor injection

In the first case you create an object then you inject the fields using `inject` method. For example in your `onCreate` of an Activity you will call this:

```
mObjectGraph.inject(this);
```

The second type of injection (constructor injection) requires that the object is created by Dagger. You simply mark the constructor with `@Inject` annotation then you can create instance like this:

```
HasInjectableConstructor instance = mObjectGraph.get(HasInjectableConstructor.class);
```

That's it. Maybe Dagger 2 will change something in this matter: [squ.re/dagger2](http://squ.re/dagger2)